# Can't centralize animation (libGdx)

Tags: java, android, animation, sprite, libgdx

I'm having problems to centralize my sprite animation can someone please give me a light?

```
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();                       
    currentFrame = walkAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);      



    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(currentFrame, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 - ((walkSheet.getWidth()/FRAME_COLS) / 2), Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2 - ((walkSheet.getHeight()/FRAME_ROWS) / 2), width / 2, height / 4);
```

My animation is being draw a few pixels to the left.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to compute the current frame's width with `walkSheet.getWidth()/FRAME_COLS`...why not just call `currentFrame.getWidth()` instead?

Comment: @damo Thanks for the answer, but it just gave me the same results, when running on desktop the animation gets draw a bit to the right and when running on my phone it's a bit to the left, maybe is not that piece of code that I must change?

Comment: I would also make sure that you defined your `TextureRegion`s correctly. The `TextureRegion` might be centered on the screen, but the sprite might not be centered within the `TextureRegion`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For x position, you have-

```
Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 - ((walkSheet.getWidth()/FRAME_COLS) / 2)
```

If each animation image is 100px wide, why don't you use-

```
private static final float WALK_ANIM_WIDTH = 100f;
```

X position would be then -

```
Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2f - WALK_ANIM_WIDTH / 2f
```

**UPDATE**:

Based from your comment, you can have something like-

```
public static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 800;
public static final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 520;

guiCam = new OrthographicCamera(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
guiCam.position.set(SCREEN_WIDTH / 2f, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2f, 0);
```

Now rather than using "Gdx.graphics.getWidth()", you can simply use SCREEN_WIDTH.

Take a look at the SuperJumper demo in libGDX. You will see how they used the viewport in game world.

Comment: Thanks, that helps me make the code easier but, what if I want to resize my animation according to different resolutions? Would it still work? I'm currentily using Gdx.graphics.getWidth / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight / 4 to make the animation resize according to the current resolution and that's what I think that is making my animation unable to be centered. How can I resolve this? I hope it's easy to understand what I'm writing since English is not my native language

Comment: @IvanCarlos It will still work as long as you use a viewport. To test it, you can resize your desktop app. :)  Take a look at the SuperJumper demo in libGDX. You will see FRUSTUM_WIDTH and FRUSTUM_HEIGHT and how they are used so that even if you resize, everything will scale accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me.Now when I rezise the window the animation is also resized but it leaves the center, when I make the screen smaller it goes to the bottom left acording to the screen size and when I make it larger the animation goes to the right and a bit to the top, how can I make the animation centralized with the camera?

Comment: Just solved it using batch.draw(currentFrame, SCREEN_WIDTH / 2f - WALK_ANIM_WIDTH / 2f, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2f - WALK_ANIM_HEIGHT / 2f); Thanks for the help I'm starting to better understand the concept :)